# Upgraded Yosemite version and it keeps showing busy cursor

Tags: macos

As Apple suggests I updated my OS and after restart it seems to get slow as it keeps showing busy cursor. Caps lock working properly. I just can't use cursor to select anything. How can I sort this out or how do I revert to old version? My old version was 10.10.2 and now .5

Comment: Spotlight indexing will be very busy for a while. If it hasn't settled down after a day or two, have a look at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/243290/troubleshooting-mac-issues

Comment: So it will keep being like that for a day or two!! Can you suggest t should I do ATM? Is there anyway to see activities going on in the beginning?

Comment: Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor - Spotlight shows in there as mds, mds_store or mdworker If any of those look to be very busy, best thing to do is wait it out. Leave the machine awake overnight & see if it's finished by tomorrow

Comment: What's actually happens, I restarted and cursor looks OK. As soon as I move it starts showing busy cursor. Is it normal? Also my memory is 4 gb

Comment: @Tetsujin I just tried to run in safe mode by holding shift key in start now it shows apple logo in start and then seems to get shutdown